# Add and update values in settings table

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ado.net, sql-server-2016

I am required to use ADO to add/update some values in a user settings table in SQL Server.  The values may already exist, if so update the value for the key, if the key does not exist, add it for the user, which may or may not exist at all in the settings table.

My user settings model which matches the DB table:

```
public class UserSettingsModel
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

How I will be getting existing settings:

```
public static List<UserSettingsModel> GetUserSettings(string userId)
{
    List<UserSettingsModel> settings = new List<UserSettingsModel>();

    using (SqlConnection c = ConnectVRS())
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"
                SELECT    SettingKey
                        , SettingValue
                FROM    UserSettings
                WHERE   UserId = @UserId
            ", c);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userId;

        using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                settings.Add(new UserSettingsModel()
                {
                    UserId = userId,
                    Key = dr[0].ToString(),
                    Value = dr[1].ToString()
                });
            }
        }
    }

    return settings;
}
```

Now, I need method(s) to add and update the settings.  I could loop over the values passed in and execute a query for each item but I seem to recall a better way?  Might be able to stack all incoming values into a single query?  Check for and add/update in the query?  All help appreciated.

---

Additional code for AddUpdate:

```
public static void AddUpdateUserSettings(List<UserSettingsModel> userSettings)
{
    DataService.LogAudit("", "Add/Update User Settings");

    using (SqlConnection c = ConnectVRS())
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"
            CREATE TABLE #TempSettings ( UserId VarChar(128), SettingKey VarChar(100), SettingValue Text );

            INSERT INTO #TempSettings ( UserId, SettingKey, SettingValue ) VALUES ('Connie', 'two', 'four')

            INSERT INTO UserSettings
            SELECT UserId, SettingKey, SettingValue FROM #TempSettings 
            WHERE SettingKey NOT IN(
                SELECT UserSettings.SettingKey FROM UserSettings
                    INNER JOIN #TempSettings ON UserSettings.UserId = #TempSettings.UserId)

            UPDATE s
                SET s.SettingValue = t.SettingValue
            FROM UserSettings s
                INNER JOIN #TempSettings t ON s.UserId = t.UserId AND s.SettingKey = t.SettingKey

            DROP TABLE #TempSettings
        ", c);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are describing a MERGE operation, check out this link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql

Answer (score 2):

You can use MERGE statement but it is an overkill for simple things like this.

You can just insert all of the values into a temp table #TempSetting

Then you can do

```
INSERT INTO UserSettings
SELECT .... FROM #TempSettings 
WHERE SettingKey NOT IN(
SELECT UserSettings.SettingKey FROM UserSettings
INNER JOIN #TempSettings ON 
UserSettings.SettingKey = #TempSettings.SettingKey)


UPDATE UserSettings
SET UserSettings.SettingValue= #TempSettings.SettingValue FROM UserSettings
INNER JOIN #TempSettings ON 
UserSettings.SettingKey = #TempSettings.SettingKey
```

Comment: I had to move the Inner Join down as it was getting an error but the query works great when testing in SSMS. Thanks!  Now, just wrapping my head around how I need to populate the temp table.  Temp code added above.

Comment: @ConnieDeCinkoCS you can either do n inserts or you can just do Values(id, key, val), (id2, key2, val2), (i3, key3, val3). Basically insert all settings into the temp table and then merge it. Since temp table is only visible in the current session/transaction you don't have to worry about race condition issue nor do you have to drop it in the end (Sql server does that for you)

Comment: Ran into an issue, as the UserId and SettingKey are a compound primary key.  Thinking I might need to just add an identity column to the table so I can than pass that into my NOT IN.

Comment: @ConnieDeCinkoCS just do the filter in the ON clause. If you can provide the full table structure I might be able to help you w/ that